# Conditional Formatting Depending on Text In Separate Cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to have one column change color (individual cells in that column, rather) depending on if there is text in a different cell in the same row. I've tried using something along the lines of =IF(($B1<>""), TRUE, FALSE) and that works, but when I try to copy that formatting to the rest of the column, the cell number that the formula references stays the same, so every cell in column A will reference cell B1 instead of changing the reference cell to B2, B3, etc... on down the column.

Comment: You would have one rule that applies to the full column with the formula you show.  You would not have separate rules for each cell in B.

Comment: After posting my question, I searched around some more and found my answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26035201/excel-conditional-formatting-depending-on-cells-on-another-column
I appreciate you taking the time to reply to my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your formula i'm assuming is the `$` sign which is an absolute reference. So if you use `$B1` in your formula, you're saying that you need to always compare against the value in column B.

using this formula should probably work for you:

```
=IF(B1<>"", TRUE, FALSE)
```

But it also depends on the range that you're applying this conditional-format on.

### TIP:

You don't even have to use the IF function, `B1<>""` returns TRUE or FASLE by default.